# Intellij is not able to fetch maven artifacts in private repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

At work we have no direct connection to the internet.
To fetch maven artifacts we need to use a local Nexus, which mirrors all of maven-central.
I have a `settings.xml` containing the needed configuration. (Hostname, password, etc.)

Running `mvn` from the command line works fine. (Both for fetching regular jars and sources.)

Intellij however is not able to fetch any artifacts. Looks like it uses the correct server, but maybe(?) does not authenticate.

I cannot see a helpful error message in intellij. However in my `.m2/repository` instead of the artifact I find a file `*.jar.lastUpdated` which says:

```
.../public-snapshots/.error=Could not transfer artifact ... from nexus (*Correct URL*):
Transfer failed for https://*correct URL*.jar
```

So it look like Intellij **tried** to fetch the file from the correct server, but was not able to do so.

**Any idea what might be the problem here, or where I could find a more detailed error message?**

(In the maven options of Intellij I already set the correct MAVEN_HOME and the correct settings.xml. According to the above message Intellij also read the settings file to replace the correct URL.)

Here is the requested settings dialog:
[image: intellij maven settings]

Also running Maven explicitly using the lifecycle targets in Intellij works fine, but any internal features like "Download sources and documentation" fail.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your intellij maven settings?

Comment: Try to delete the .idea folder into your project. Then reimport all through the refresh button situated in the upper right corner under the maven menu entry. If this doesn't works try to invalidate cache and restart too. Just to be sure it isn't a caching issue.

Comment: @RobertoManfreda I already tried "invalidate and restart". I also did a new fresh checkout (without any idea data) and opened it as a new project. - It looks like it grabs the URL from settings.xml and ignores the password there. - But without any logs it's just wild guessing...

Comment: Tried [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91967)? I think some issue with CA

Comment: Also try to check the 'print exception stacktraces' option trying to get more output

Comment: The first question is: Do those source artifacts exist in your internal repository? Furthermore which version of IDEA IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: @khmarbaise, Yes, it exists. Everything works well from the command line. (That's the current workaround.) The version of IntelliJ is the one provided at work, which happens to be 2019.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: First thing upgrade to IDEA IntelliJ 2020.X (2020.3.x) . Several improvements/etc.) furthermore I see something in your error message `public-snapshots...Transfer failed for https://*correct URL*.jar` isn't the configuration in your settings pointing to a single group repository in Nexus? Can you please post the settings.xml (of course without passwords..) ...

Comment: How do you know it does not work in IDE: what exact error do you see? If you use non-default repository, spceify it explicitly in IDE settings (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Local Repository -> **Override** option). Also set **Debug** for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Output level:** then **reload All Maven Projects** in Maven tool window and provide the output in idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action)  and from Build tool window **Sync** tab.

Comment: For the IDE to re-downloading of dependencies - delete these `.lastUpdated` file from the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issues with maven repository and Intellij. What I found is under **.idea directory there is jarRepositories.xml** file which by default points to **"Maven central repository"** i.e., **"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"**. However, as we have organization specific maven repository under **settings.xml**, I noticed, Intellij tries to download repository from maven repository mentioned in jarRepositoris.xml and not that from Settings.xml. I verified this by executing "mvn clean install" from command prompt with building project from Intellij. Later when I changed jarRepositories.xml to point to organization specific maven repo, I was able to build project from Intellij as well.